# Tabla Usuarios MySQL

Tags: base-de-datos

actualmente estoy creando una base de datos con MySQL , y tengo que crear 2 tipos de usuarios , Super-Admin y Moderadores , lo que estaba pensando era en crear una tabla User y las respectivas tablas Super-Admin y Moderadores , lo que pretendo es que crear un inventario donde se guarden una lista de productos y que el acceso de los moderadores sea solo para editar precios nombres , medidas , y obviamente el Super-Admin tendría el control total. Lo que quiero saber es si esta es la manera ideal para crear una base de datos con 2 tipos de usuarios o hay una alternativa mejor.

Comment: Bien por ti, pero ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: No se entiende, cual es la duda?

Comment: Lo que quiero es saber si tengo que crear Una tabla Usuario General y despues crear ambas tablas de Super-Admin y Moderadores , y  enlazarlas a las tablas , categorias , precios , medida , detalles o es mejor crear una Tabla Usuario - Tipo - Usuario-Tipo

Comment: Es solo una opinión, pero para eso tu tabla de usuarios debería estar enlazada con una tabla de roles o si tus usuarios tendrán múltiples roles entonces crear una tabla intermedia que almacene los ids de los usuarios y los ids de los roles que tendrán, te recomiendo estudies acerca de normalización en bd

Comment: @SalazarCDiego [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/421181/edit) tu pregunta y agrega ese dato. Ademas ya que pides "saber algo" puede estar basada en opiones por lo que podria ser cerrada

Comment: ehhh que? tenes una tabla usuarios.. con roles.. para que queres mas tablas? no vas a crear una tabla por rol... eso es un no no... como mucho, como dice Beta, tendras una tabla intermedia si alguien puede tener mas de un rol...